# How to use boolean flag with cxxopts and command line?

Tags: c++, linux, command-line-arguments

I defined:

```
options.add_options()
  ("m, monitor", "Monitor current state", cxxopts::value<bool>()->default_value("true"));
```

How do I use flag `m` in command line to run `test` executable on Linux?

This:

```
./test -m "false"
./test -m false
```

doesn't work.

---

My case has `true` as default value for `m` and I want to run `test` with `m` having `false` value. Is it possible?

Comment: From `cxxopt` docs: "...writing -o by itself will set option o to true...", i.e. writing `./test -m` already means you set it `true`. https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts?tab=readme-ov-file#boolean-values

Comment: Long time since I worked with cxxopts, but doesn't that mean the result will be `false` if the option is *not* an argument, and `true` if it is?

Comment: @vahancho That wasn't clear to me after reading that text. My case is different, though. I've set `true` as a default value for `m` and I'm looking for a command, which will set it to `false`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Not in my case. See the comment above.

Comment: The default value of a bool value should either be `true` or `false`, not `"false"`. That makes it look like you really want a string type instead. And the underlying problem is that `bool` is basically a "argument is provided" check. Which makes sense for a "monitor" option. If it's not given as an argument, then no monitoring should happen; If it is given as an argument, then you should monitor.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Not according to https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts. See an example with `"false"` there.